# Finding an optimal $p$ such that $u \in L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

We have an $L^2$ function $u$ defined on $\mathbb{R^2}$ with compact support such that $u \in H^{2/3}$ (H stands for Sobolev spaces, as always), $\partial_y u \in L^2$, and $(x\partial_y - y\partial_x)u \in L^2$. I want to conclude that $u$ lies in some higher order $L^p$ space, that is, for some $p > 2$. Ideally, I would like to use all three pieces of information so that it leads to a high enough $p$. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: Is there some book that contains exercises specifically of this nature?

Comment: Since $x \in L^\infty$, the third assumption can be stated as $y \, \partial_x u \in L^2$. I don't know if this help...